How to serve a nuxt 3 webapp with unix socket instead of http
Is it possible to build a Nuxt 3 App so that it will use a unix socket instead of serving on a local tcp port? I am intending to make an app with pywebview and nuxt3. I want the pywebview to display the nuxt3 app with unix socket instead of http so that I don't have to expose the nuxt app on any local tcp port

I think this link may answer your question.
You will need to install socat.
Installation
sudo apt-get install socat (on ubuntu)

brew install socat (on mac)

After that you may use this steps :
Set up socket

To use a Unix socket for serving a Nuxt 3 app, you will need to make a
few modifications to the default configuration. Here are the steps:
Create a Unix socket file: You can create a Unix socket file using the
socat command. For example: socat TCP-LISTEN:3000,reuseaddr,fork
UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/nuxt.sock This will create a Unix socket file at
/tmp/nuxt.sock and bind it to the TCP port 3000.

Configure Nuxt 3 to use the Unix socket

In the nuxt.config.js file,
you will need to specify the Unix socket file as the hostname and
the TCP port as the port. For example: export default {   server: {
host: '/tmp/nuxt.sock',
port: 3000   } } This will tell Nuxt 3 to use the Unix socket file at /tmp/nuxt.sock and the TCP port 3000 for serving the app.

Start the Nuxt 3 app:

You can start the Nuxt 3 app using the nuxt
command. For example: nuxt This will start the Nuxt 3 app and bind it
to the Unix socket file at /tmp/nuxt.sock and the TCP port 3000.

Here the link and source: https://onexception.dev/news/1365226/nuxt3-app-with-unix-socket-serving
